# app.config.from_object('config') causing uWSGI Error?

Tags: python, nginx, flask

Trying to deploy a flask app on nginx + uwsgi.  It works locally, and I'm trying to host it somewhere new.  I changed my config parameters to suit the new environment, but it seemed nothing worked.  After systematically eliminating all lines in my `__init__.py` file, I found that only by commenting out this line:

```
app.config.from_object('config')
```

---would render my app.  Even when I removed all lines from my config.py file, or included only safe values like:

```
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt','png'])
```

---it was still the case that the call `app.config.from_object('config')` caused a uWSGI error.  (I also tried calling config.py, same thing.)

What could be going on here, and how can I setup config like I do locally, as [described here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/config/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it was the location of the `config.py`.  It should be one folder level higher than the `__init__.py` file.  I had them in the same subfolder, `appname/appname`, where it should only be `appname/config.py` and `appname/appname/__init__.py`.